# Change line draw style in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

In order for the edges of the graph in the figure to look beautiful, I want to add the following set of options to each edge: `[draw=white, double=black, very thick]`. At the same time, I would like to draw the edges like this:

```
\draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
\draw (1, 0) -- (0, 1);
```

and not so:

```
\draw[draw=white, double=black, very thick] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw[draw=white, double=black, very thick] (1,0) -- (0,1);
```

I tried using `scope`, but for some reason it doesn't work (although for simple settings like `[red]` everything works fine).

How do I set up the environment correctly so that every `\draw` uses the style I want?

MWE:

[image: 1]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\MyDraw{\draw[draw=white, double=black, very thick]}

    \foreach \i in {1, ..., 6} {
        \MyDraw (c) -- (b \i);
    }

    \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
    \draw (1, 0) -- (0, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add style to every path:

[image: 1]

```
\documentclass[border=0.618cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={double=black},draw=white,very thick]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw (1,0) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```